# How do I change the startup directory in babun?

Tags: cygwin, startup, babun

Searches have suggested that I should add a line at the end of my `.bashrc` that reads

```
cd /the/directory
```

but that doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: `.bashrc` will work only if you are using bash as shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set it in the .babunrc

Comment: Will do as soon as I'm allowed to ( a few minutes ^^)

Answer (score 0):

Doh! Added the line to `.zshrc` instead and it seems to work fine now.